# How to get the latest version of a all previously distinctable objects within a single query in django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model with a `version` field.

```py
class Workflow(models.Model):
    ...
    process_id = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=100) # not unique!
    version = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
```

I'm trying to find the latest version for each `process_id` within a single query. Basically, I want to do the following:

```py
class WorkflowFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    only_latest_versions = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='get_only_latest_versions')

    def get_only_latest_versions(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        if value:
            workflows = []
            for worflow in queryset.distinct('process_id'):
                workflow_ = queryset.filter(process_id=worflow.process_id,
                                            enabled=True).latest('version')
                workflows.append(workflow_)
            return workflows  # even if I wanted to do like this I can't because I must return a QuerySet
        return queryset
```

How can I do the above with a single query?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

I could retrieve the latest versions with the following query:

```
queryset.filter(enabled=True).values('process_id').annotate(max_version=Max('version'))
```

However, it returns, obviously, only the `process_id` and `max_version`. How can I retrieve all fields or the objects themselves with this approach?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem PostegreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Subquery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) together with [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef).

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
subquery = Workflow.objects.filter(process_id=OuterRef('process_id'), enabled=True).order_by('-version')
queryset = Workflow.objects.filter(version=Subquery(subquery.values('version')[:1]))
```

The variable `queryset` is a [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/) of `Workflow` containing the latest version for each `process_id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I won't be able to test it until monday, but I have two questions: 1) with your approach we're going to hit the db twice, aren't we? 2) where did `aux` come from? It' was suppose to be `subquery`, right?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio 1) No it's not gonna hit the db twice, because it is a sub query so it is executed together with another query. 2)Thanks for the heads up for the aux variable ;).